# invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘FILE*’ - ROOT

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, printf, root-framework

I am using cern's data analysis framework, ROOT. What I am trying to do is export in an ascii file the contents of a TH1F histogram. My sample code is the following

```
#include "TH1.h"
#include "TH1F.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void histo2ascii(TH1* hist){

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("movie_small.txt");

    for (int i=1; i<=hist->GetNbinsX(); i++){
        if(hist->GetBinCenter(i)>5.e-3 && hist->GetBinCenter(i)<7.e-3){
            //myfile << (float) hist->GetBinCenter(i) << "\t" << hist->GetBinContent(i) << endl;
            fprintf(myfile, "%.17g \t %d", hist->GetBinCenter(i), (int) hist->GetBinContent(i));
        }
    }

    myfile.close();

}
```

The problem is that, when I compile it (OK, through cint, using .L code.C++ :/) I get the following error

> `invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘FILE*’`

at `fprintf` line.

Any idea on why this might be happening?

Comment: I think you need to [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and start over with how file input and output works in C++ with streams. Hint: If you used `std::cout` to print anything you got the basics for output.

Comment: what does "(OK, through cint, using .L code.C++ :/)" mean?

Comment: @M.M ROOT uses an interpreter to run C++ code that is loaded via `.L filename.C`. Executing `.L filename.C+` compiles the code into a library rather than depending on an interpreter. The second `+` is a typo, but a harmless one- ROOT still interprets it the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fprintf` expects a `FILE*`, not an `ofstream`. You cannot use the c-style printing functions with c++ streams this way.

Use the stream as you did in your commented out line just above the `fprintf` line. If you want to set the precision, use:

```
myfile << std::setprecision(2) << hist->GetBinCenter(i).
```

Don't forget to include `<iomanip>`. For a list of stream manipulators, see [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Edit: As mentioned in the comments, `myfile` gets implicitly converted to `void*` since `fprintf` expects a pointer. This is why it complains about `void*` instead of `ofstream`.

Comment: The complaint comes because of [this conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). The `fprintf` expects a pointer, so the compiler uses the conversion operator. And since C++ is stronger typed than C the compiler will then complain about converting `void*` to `FILE*`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the explanation. I didn't know they had this implicit conversion before c++11.

Comment: It was so a stream could be used in a boolean expression. Why they originally used pointers for this I don't know.